# Kotlin Receiver Name Clash

Tags: java, kotlin, build

When running the following code snippet, the compiler is attempting to resolve the method `isEmpty` against a receiver defined in `kotlin.collections` for reasons I don't fully understand.  The method `isEmpty` is defined within `java.util.Optional`.  If I replace `isEmpty` with `!isPresent`, the code works as expected.

```
private fun getThreadCount(param: Optional<String>): Int {
        return if(param.isEmpty) {
            DEFAULT_THREAD_COUNT
        } else {
            val threads = param.get()
            try {
                threads.toInt()
            } catch (ex: NumberFormatException) {
                throw RuntimeException("Failed to parse threads parameter: $threads")
            }
        }
    }
```

```
> Task :compileKotlin FAILED
e: /home/.../TaskParams.kt: (51, 25): Function invocation 'isEmpty(...)' expected
e: /home/.../TaskParams.kt: (51, 25): Unresolved reference. None of the following 
candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch: 
public inline fun <T> Array<out ???>.isEmpty(): Boolean defined in kotlin.collections
public inline fun BooleanArray.isEmpty(): Boolean defined in kotlin.collections
public inline fun ByteArray.isEmpty(): Boolean defined in kotlin.collections
public inline fun CharArray.isEmpty(): Boolean defined in kotlin.collections
public inline fun CharSequence.isEmpty(): Boolean defined in kotlin.text
public inline fun DoubleArray.isEmpty(): Boolean defined in kotlin.collections
public inline fun FloatArray.isEmpty(): Boolean defined in kotlin.collections
public inline fun IntArray.isEmpty(): Boolean defined in kotlin.collections
public inline fun LongArray.isEmpty(): Boolean defined in kotlin.collections
public inline fun ShortArray.isEmpty(): Boolean defined in kotlin.collections
```

This is being compiled against Kotlin 1.3.72

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`java.util.Optional` `isEmpty()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#isEmpty()) was added in Java 11. [The Android version of `Optional`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Optional) (or whatever your target is) does not have it.

Just go with the `!isPresent()`, or `!isPresent` with kotlin syntax sugar.